# Make a search filter

Tags: php, mysql, filter, searchfiltercollection

I have 5 fields in database. Query where clause has 5 parameters.

now if I pass no parameter it should retrieve all records. If I pass only 2nd parameter it retrieves based on that parameter. but if I pass 2nd and any parameter after that it only takes 2nd parameter, it not uses the parameter after 2nd parameter. I am using or operator:

**query**

```
select address from table1 where state ='' or city ='Aa' or address_line ='school'
```

it should retrieve all records that has City = Ab and address_line = school. But it retrieves based on city , it not uses the address_line.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: i dont understand,,

Comment: Why you say and by words and write or in your query??

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to chance the second **OR** to a **AND** for it to pick also the second parameter

And you litteraly said it in your explanation "and" so why stil write or.

Comment: because query may have 2nd param or may not.

Comment: yes. u use OR if there 2 answers. and only 1 good answer. and AND if you have 2 correct answers in this kind of situations